# Compilation error "Incomplete definition of type 'struct proc'"

Tags: c, xcode, macos, kernel-extension

We are trying to monitor the processes using the **kauth process listener (KAUTH_SCOPE_PROCESS)**. One of the arguments for the kauth process listener is a pointer to proc_t (struct proc)

We want to access some of the members of proc_t, for example, **p_name**(process name), **p_textvp** (vnode of process executable) etc. We wrote a code however while compiling, we were getting compilation error "Incomplete definition of type 'struct proc'“

Would be appreciable if someone guides me to fix this.

```
static int ProcessScopeListener( 
kauth_cred_t credential, 
void* idata, 
kauth_action_t action, 
uintptr_t arg0, 
uintptr_t arg1, 
uintptr_t arg2, 
uintptr_t arg3 
) 
{ 
proc_t process = (proc_t) arg0; 
…

//Compilation error in the following two lines

char* proc_name = &process->p_name[0]; 

struct vnode* p_textvp = process-> p_textvp;
﻿
. 
. 
. 

return KERN_SUCESS; 
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Since you're trying to access through a `proc_t`, which you say has type `struct proc *`, then presumably you forgot to include the header file that defines `struct proc`, so obviously it can't generate code for things like `process->p_name` without knowing the structure definition.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yeah, you are correct. I'm coding with Xcode and using the Kernel Framework. There are no traces of **struct proc definition** in any of the header files exposed in the Kernel Framework, not even sys/proc.h. But by exploring the darwin-xnu source code, I could see the **struct proc**  defined in **proc_internal.h**. So, is it recommended to add only these required header files directly to my project and work with it? Please point me in the right direction if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That struct is opaque, dereferencing pointers to it directly is not supported, as its layout may change from OS version to OS version.

Use the accessor functions such as `proc_name()` instead. Note that `p_textvp` is always `NULL` so there is no accessor.